# How many layer can be added Google Maps ?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am exploring Google Maps Javascript API to start our new project. Does anyone know how many layers can be added to Google Maps?

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps API v3 doesn't stack the information as layers. There is a fixed group of layers, and each entity gets pushed into the corresponding layer based on its type.

If you meant overlays, then Google Maps has a layer in particular to add each overlay. I've never loaded that many overlays to make the browser unresponsive, but in general that's the google way. You are free to load thousands of entities of a given type, but it's up to you to decide what's the practical limit to keep browser responsiveness.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know how many KML type layers we can add to the map?

Answer (score 0):

10 layers -if you add more you get a message a message to say there are too many layers to display. I haven't discovered yet how many features you can add to a layer